# Extracting information from a dict within a dict

Tags: python

I have a list of specifications that have a dict of properties associated with them:

```
specs = {
    'spec': {'name': 'color',   'value': 'blue'},
    'spec': {'name':'size', 'value':'8'}
}
```

Ultimately, I'd like to extract only size = 8 from this list, but the order of where `size` is in the dict changes (ie. it's not always the second element).

Is there a more efficient way to find the dict that `size` is in, other than looping through each dict item in specs?

I know that I could do specs [size] if it were located as a key.. but it's not.

Comment: I don't think that `specs` is what you want.  You have a duplicate key, so you'll only get one `'spec': {subdict}` pair.  You may have simplified it too much for SO.

Comment: Ok sorry it's actually a list of a JSON response.

Comment: What is your raw JSON?

Comment: Yes. each list entry is a dict with [{'spec': {keypairs(dict)}}]

Comment: A list like `[{'name': 'color',   'value': 'blue'},  {'name':'size', 'value':'8'}]`, you mean?

Comment: No a list like [{'spec':{'name': 'color', 'value': 'blue'}}], [{{'spec', 'name':'size', 'value':'8'}}]

Comment: please edit the question to reflect that specs is a list

Comment: @user1328021 Update the question, with some actual correctly formatted data that someone can paste into their favourite interpreter and use

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any more efficient than looping through the list. You can write a nice, compact list comprehension if you want to:

```
print [x['spec']['value'] for x in specs if x['spec']['name'] == 'size']
#  [8]
```

Comment: would still have to go through the loop. The nested structure with the mostly useless 'spec' makes looping kind of awkward...

Comment: Yeah, agreed but I have no control over it as it's from an API call. Many thanks.

Comment: @user1328021 On a side note - there's also a `jsonpath` module (which I've had relatively okay luck with) - that might be worth looking up depending on exactly what you're trying to do